# Render Issue with Metaballs

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, settings

Currently rendering someone else's Blender file, but for some reason the metaballs look real weird when rendered, while ok in the viewport. Is there a reason for that and if so, how can I fix it?
I've tried importing the collection to a new file but the issue persists.

[image: Shader]

[image: Meatball]

[image: Force Field]

[image: Render Result]

[image: Viewport Image]

Comment: Why is the metaball Resolution property for rendering not set equal to the one for the viewport? Did you check for hidden/non renderable objects in your scene? Can you describe what exactly you are not satified of?

Comment: @Carlo It was set up like that when I recevied the file, but changing it does not fix my issue, unfortunately. The thing I'm not satisfied with / or don't understand the reason for are the horizontal lines going through the metaballs on the final render ( it's technically an animation ) and why can't I figure out a way to eliminate them. I want to assume it's a simple fix but I've never really tinkered with metaballs before so I don't really know. I've tried recreating the file, duplicating the collection but the visual artefacts persist so I assume it's not just a bug.

Comment: Would you be able to uplad your file, or a part of it, so we can inspect it allo around and look for clues?